# Loading new form has a error in if statement?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, if-statement

i keep getting a error when trying to load a new form on my if statement? at the end of the frm.show();

```
 if (listBox1.FindString(metroTextBox1.Text) != -1)
            if (listBox2.FindString(metroTextBox2.Text) != -1)
                MessageBox.Show("Found it!");
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Show();



        else
        {
        MessageBox.Show("TRY AGAIN");
        }
```

Comment: and the error is....??

Comment: Expected } but when I add one it gives errors for the rest of the code

Answer (score 3):

You need braces around the body of the if block:

```
if (listBox1.FindString(metroTextBox1.Text) != -1)
{
    if (listBox2.FindString(metroTextBox2.Text) != -1)
            MessageBox.Show("Found it!");
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("TRY AGAIN");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an `else` with no corresponding `if`:

```
frm.Show();
else
{
```

An `else` *must* be paired with an `if`, not just structurally in the code but even just semantically in basic logic.  Perhaps you meant to surround some of your code with brackets?:

```
if (listBox1.FindString(metroTextBox1.Text) != -1)
{
    if (listBox2.FindString(metroTextBox2.Text) != -1)
        MessageBox.Show("Found it!");
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show();
}
```

Or:

```
if (listBox1.FindString(metroTextBox1.Text) != -1)
    if (listBox2.FindString(metroTextBox2.Text) != -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Found it!");
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Show();
    }
```

It's really up to you which lines of code constitute the `if` block.  But the point is that any given `else` needs to be paired with an `if`.  It can't exist by itself.

(Note: Using sensible indentation and other whitespace makes your code more readable which in turn makes errors like this more obvious.)

Answer (score 1):

format and enclose the code between { }

## Example:

```
if (listBox1.FindString(metroTextBox1.Text) != -1){
    if (listBox2.FindString(metroTextBox2.Text) != -1){
        MessageBox.Show("Found it!");
    }
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show();
}else{
    MessageBox.Show("TRY AGAIN");
}
```